# ElasticBeanstalk worker environment stuck in "Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes." and then times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am defining an EB worker environment via Cloud Formation Template:

```
  EbWorkerApplication:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-worker"
      Description: !Ref DeploymentDescription
    
  EbWorkerEnvironment:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
    DependsOn: EbWorkerApplication
    Properties:
      Tier:
        Name: "Worker"
        Type: "SQS/HTTP"
      ApplicationName: !Ref EbWorkerApplication
      EnvironmentName: !Sub "${EnvName}-worker"
      SolutionStackName: !Ref SolutionStackName
      OptionSettings:
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: SecurityGroups
          Value:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              !Sub "${EnvName}-app-sg"
        - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
          OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          Value: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
        - Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment'
          OptionName: ServiceRole
          Value: !Ref EbServiceRole

          ... plus remaining stuff not relevant ...
```

I have a similar, WebServer environment that spins right up.

The worker environment above though, fails to come up. This is the error:

```
2:58am Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.     
12:57am Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].     
12:57am [Instance: i-0214d84820a734097] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..     
12:56am Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.   
12:55am Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
```

What could cause this?

Comment: If you have similar EB env, that works, what are the differences? Is the new one in custom VPC?

Comment: the similar env that works is a WebServer, the failing one is a Worker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular issue was resolved by setting an explicit `MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true` in the Subnet definitions (outside of the code shown in the question).

I now have a [different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690900/elasticbeanstalk-worker-node-fails-to-launch-sqsd-service-failed).